# Is it possible to capture the nodename or hostname in ingress controller logs?

Tags: nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I am new to k8s and want to know how to get the hostname in ingress-controller logs.

I checked the official document here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/log-format/#log-format but did not find any option. So, Is there any way to capture the hostname in logs? I see this option "use-forwarded-headers". Wondering what is the purpose of 'use-forwarded-headers'?